# getting Incorrect syntax near ',' error

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I do some mistake here but I can't see what? any idea?

```
declare @out nvarchar(50);

exec dbo.CBT_Registration_CreateUserAccount (SELECT NEWID()), (SELECT CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID())), (SELECT CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID())), (SELECT CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID())), 
(SELECT CONVERT(UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,'270b5adc-873f-4b69-8e70-1954228aa16e')), (SELECT CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID())), (SELECT CONVERT(UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,'37781810-3a49-4ce0-922d-54543b0bacde')), (SELECT CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID())),
'GBP',(SELECT CONVERT(UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,'4ee4f84d-24ad-4e0d-a3b8-d9a5d1949d46')), @out out

select @out
```

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3 Incorrect syntax near ','. Msg 102,
>   Level 15, State 1, Line 3 Incorrect syntax near ','. Msg 102, Level
>   15, State 1, Line 3 Incorrect syntax near ','. Msg 102, Level 15,
>   State 1, Line 3 Incorrect syntax near ','. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1,
>   Line 4 Incorrect syntax near ','. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
>   Incorrect syntax near ','. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
>   Incorrect syntax near ','. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
>   Incorrect syntax near ','. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
>   Incorrect syntax near ','.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your exec command as below:

You have misplaced opening and closing small brackets.

```
exec dbo.CBT_Registration_CreateUserAccount (SELECT NEWID(), (SELECT CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID())), (SELECT CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID())), (SELECT CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID())), 
(SELECT CONVERT(UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,'270b5adc-873f-4b69-8e70-1954228aa16e')), (SELECT CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID())), (SELECT CONVERT(UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,'37781810-3a49-4ce0-922d-54543b0bacde')), (SELECT CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID())),
'GBP',(SELECT CONVERT(UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,'4ee4f84d-24ad-4e0d-a3b8-d9a5d1949d46')), @out out)
```